# Deleting Community AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What happens when you make private/delete/de-register an AMI that has been shared with the AWS AMI Catalog?

Is the catalog entry now a dead link or does it automatically disappear?

Will you have to go through the submission process again to re-add the AMI to the catalog?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "AWS AMI Catalog" ?  Are you talking about the lists of generally public AMIs? or the AWS Marketplace https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/ ?  or this: https://aws.amazon.com/amis/ ?

Comment: The third one. They have a submission form for it: https://aws.amazon.com/amis/new

Comment: The link will no longer work to start an instance of that AMI.  You should edit or delete the AMI listing through this page: https://aws.amazon.com/your-account/community-content

Comment: Well okay. I think that answers my questions.